# Looking for efficient algorithm to find nearest integer in a list of integers

Tags: javascript, list, integer

Here's the situation. I have a sorted list of integers representing events that need to be fired at a certain millisecond. That list might look like:

```
0
1500
5000
9348
89234
109280
109281
109283
150000
```

I then have a `playhead` that typically moves forward every 100ms, but can random seek and scrub forwards and backwards as well. That playhead is not guaranteed to be a multiple of 100, but can be floored to that multiple without any real problem.

My challenge is to be able to efficiently find the closest element in the list that less than or equal to the current playhead. Average length of list is between 300 and 1500 elements. I can optimize for forward at set intervals fairly easily, but random seek is a little more complicated.

Makes me wish I hand't slept through algorithms class.

Comment: Simplest way: Loop through the array backwards and pick the first element that is less than or equal to the playhead. Have you tried that, is this too inefficient for your use case?

Comment: The challenge is to *efficiently* find...Linear search is not efficient.

Comment: It may well be *efficient enough* though. 1500 elements ain't *that* much for a modern machine.

Comment: Linear search is what we are doing now. 1500 isn't much, but 1500 in JS with video playing in the browser is a little different.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Divide and conquer algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) is the best suit.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a modified binary search.  Since the list is in sorted order, a binary search will vastly improve search performance over a linear search and if you don't know anything about the spacing of the items in the array, you can't do much better than a binary search.  The binary search will need to be slightly modified because you're not looking for equality, but something that is as near without going over.

Here's an actual algorithm that keeps dividing the search data in 1/2 (going with the top half or bottom half each time based on a comparison to the test value) until it's down to only one element:

```
var testData = [0,1500,5000,9348,89234,109280,109281,109283,150000];

function findNearest(data, val) {
    if (!data || !data.length) {
        return(null);
    }
    var lowest = 0, mid;
    var highest = data.length - 1;
    while (true) {    
        if (lowest == highest) {
            return(lowest);
        }
        mid = Math.ceil(((highest - lowest) / 2) + lowest);
        if (data[mid] == val) {
            return(mid);
        }
        else if (data[mid] < val) {
            lowest = mid;
        } else {
            highest = Math.max(lowest, mid - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

And, a working test program: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rWk2X/

Note: this code assumes all values in the array are in sorted order and the array is not empty.

If you give it an array that has no values less than the target value, it will return 0 which may be a special case you need to handle unless are sure that the first value in the array is always less than the target value (e.g. always zero).

If you give it an array that has no values greater than the target value, it will return the last value in the array (as it should) and this is not a special case, just the desired answer.

Comment: As this seemed like an interesting algorithm problem, I added a working code example to my answer.  If you play with this, be careful as it's very easy to get an infinite loop.  I actually had a max number of iterations coded into my code during testing (it would abort after 1000 iterations with an error) just to avoid infinite loops.

Comment: This looks like the best solution. Is there a specific set of inputs that will result in the infinite loop?

Comment: @turing1 - inputs won't cause an infinite loop.  You can pass anything in and it is handled fine as the comments after the code try to explain.  Only if you mess with the code in the function and goof it up do you run a risk of an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a sorted list, use a binary search. You can do better, but then you have to make additional assumptions (e.g. you must assume even distribution of numbers, which I do not think is the case). You can read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I faced that problem some time ago and made some execution time comparisons.

Take a look [here](http://www.jmvc.org/test_array) . (the sample do NOT works with IE)

The fourth implementation seem really to rule compared to dumb binary search.

Hope it helps.

Bye